# Run fingerprint Scanner on Web Application in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, fingerprint

I have a web application and I need to integrate a fingerprint scanning service.I have a scanner but i don't know how to pass the data to my Web application.Please help if some body knows about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fingerprint scanner is a usb one, you might want to look at WebUSB: https://wicg.github.io/webusb/

But this only works in Chrome at the moment : [Can I Use : WebUSB](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webusb)